# What movie title does this represent?

Tags: rebus

Here's a rebus that involves no math skill, and is designed to be simple.

**What movie title is represented below?**

[image]

Comment: Might be simple for you... I had no idea. Where I come from, that cut of meat is a chop and the wee red fella is a devil. I had no idea what the Chinese glyphs were.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Thanks for the feedback. So, are you saying that it was challenging but fun, or simply too hard, or neither? Also, are you sure chop isn't [something different](https://www.google.com/search?q=chop+vs+shank&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=what+is+chop+cut)?

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker note: simple is not the same thing as easy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the movie is

> The Shawshank Redemption

The first line is

> The 
> Because all the articles, with "the" missing

The second line is

> Shaw
>  Because S plus( not pitch, not roll but yaw) = Syaw which sounds like shaw

The Third line is

> Shank Redemption
>  Because Shank of meat+red+imp+the chinese character "Shun" = shankredimpshun which sounds like Shank Redemption

Comment: Ah, very clever!

Comment: @JLee Of course, it seems obvious now

Comment: Wow, even with this explanation, I find it hard! I had to look up the words yaw, shank and shun, and blindly accept the fact that syaw sounds like shaw to understand it.

Comment: @physicalattraction simple is not the same thing as easy